# Cython ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_world)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython

I successfully used Cython to convert `.py` to `.pyd`, but have been running into difficulties trying to import cythonized modules afterwards.

---

**setup.py**

```py
from setuptools import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("world.py")
)
```

**world.py**

```
print('Hello World')
```

---

When I try to import using `import world`, it gives me the following error:

```
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_world)
```

I am using `Windows 8.1 64bit` and `Python 3.7.7 32bit`.

I have been trying different strategies for hours. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This should work. Are you definitely compiling it using the same version of Python that you're running it with (you should make it explicit _exactly_ how you're compiling it in the question)? Are you renaming any files manually yourself and just not telling us?

Comment: No it is just as what you see. Am using the latest cython version too. Like stated the compile process did not give any error . Only when i try to import the .pyd . Its weird , is only hello world.Am yet to test on a bigger file.

Comment: You might try something like `dumpbin /symbols` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dumpbin-reference?view=msvc-160) to see what it does define. You're looking for things with `init` in